# UUID shown as integer in rest-framework

Tags: python, django

This is my `model`,`serializer` and 'admin`

```
class UserData(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published',default=timezone.now)   

class UserDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Genre
        fields = ('id','pub_date')
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = UserData()
        user_data.save()
        return user_data

class UserDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["id","pub_date"]
    search_fields = ['id']
```

in admin screen id field is shown like

[image]

but in rest-framework, id shown as integer.

[image]

How can I fix this??

---

Thank you for @periwinkle comment

I changed

```
class UserDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(format='hex_verbose') // add this
    class Meta:
        model = Genre
        fields = ('id','pub_date')
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = UserData()
        user_data.save()
    return user_data
```

After this, when `POST` url to create new data.

it shows error

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "id": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

However id has default value, so there is something wrong.

Comment: Is there a reason why the UserDataSerializer has Genre in the model Meta and not UserData?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can specify the uuid format explicitly in your model. This is from the drf [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#uuidfield) about UUID:

```
Signature: UUIDField(format='hex_verbose')

format: Determines the representation format of the uuid value
'hex_verbose' - The canonical hex representation, including hyphens: "5ce0e9a5-5ffa-654b-cee0-1238041fb31a"
'hex' - The compact hex representation of the UUID, not including hyphens: "5ce0e9a55ffa654bcee01238041fb31a"
'int' - A 128 bit integer representation of the UUID: "123456789012312313134124512351145145114"
'urn' - RFC 4122 URN representation of the UUID: "urn:uuid:5ce0e9a5-5ffa-654b-cee0-1238041fb31a" Changing the format parameters only affects representation values. All formats are accepted by to_internal_value
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I put `id = serializers.UUIDField(format='hex_verbose')` in `UserDataSerializer` but after this I try to add new entry, There comes error     `"id": [
        "This field is required."
    ]`